# Adding native library jni on a cordova android project

Tags: android, cordova, android-ndk, java-native-interface, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to build a custom plugin on a cordova project using jni, I have .c and .h files and an Android.mk file. to do that I put all files on a directory jni on the cordova plugin, after that I have installed that plugin on a cordova project and I tried to get the methods of that native library like this:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("engine");
}

// ----------- NATIVE FUNCTION --------------------

private native String computeLocation();
```

After compilation I get this:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.example.plugin.AffichageGPSActivity.computeLocation:(DDD)[D
07-25 12:38:54.086 14346-14362/io.cordova.hellocordova W/System.err:     at com.example.plugin.AffichageGPSActivity.computeLocation(Native Method)
```

It's the first time that I'm doing this, so i don't have a good idea how it work.

Please HELP! thx..

Comment: Please add the relevant C code and makefiles, and show the surrounding class(es) and package name for the Java code where the native method is declared.

Comment: @K.Walid Better check this out - https://github.com/clement360/Cordova-Hello-JNI-Plugin

Comment: I used it already, the problem that I have only .c and .h files and a make file, I don't have an .so
one more thing, from the cordoba-hello-jni-example, i took just the declaration of stringfromjni() method and put it on another file .java, of course i added the loadLibrary("hello-jni"), and the compiler say that the native stringfromjni() not found. it work only when is declared on helloJni.java

Comment: You can't move native methods unless you cange the names of the corresponding C functions accordingly.